# Gradient descent against fixed orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, gradient-descent

Given $c$ orthonormal vectors $\mathbf y_1, \mathbf y_2, \dots, \mathbf y_c \in \mathbb R^n$, I have the following cost function to minimize.

$$ J ({\bf x}) := -\frac{1}{1 + \frac1c \sum\limits_{i=1}^c \exp \left({\bf y}_i^\top {\bf x} \right)} $$

The gradient of this function is a linear combination of $\mathbf y_i$:
$$\nabla_\mathbf x J=\frac{J^2}{c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)\mathbf y_i}$$

Therefore, as optimization proceeds, $\mathbf x$ is pulled towards the subspace spanned by $\mathbf y_i$. Intuitively, as $\mathbf x$ is updated with gradient descent, $\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x$ should decrease for each $\mathbf y_i$, which should align $\mathbf x$ away from all $\mathbf y_i$ in the limit:
$$\lim_{\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x\to-\infty} \frac{\sum_i\mathbf y_i^T}{\sqrt c}\cdot\frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|} = -1$$

Is my intuition correct? If so, how can I proceed to prove the alignment formally?

**Update:**

If $\mathbf x$ is initialized to $\mathbf 0$, then the proof is straightforward, since $\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x = k$ for all $i$ at each step.

$$\nabla_\mathbf x J=s\sum_i{\mathbf y_i}$$

where $$s=\frac{J^2}{c}\exp(k)$$

The GD updates then simply integrate the scaled $\sum_i{\mathbf y_i}$ over $t$ steps:
$$\mathbf x^t = -\sum_t s_t \sum_i \mathbf y_i$$
Thus the direction of of $\mathbf x^t$ is always in the opposite direction of $\sum \mathbf y_i$. Hence the proof.

On the other hand, if $\mathbf x$ is randomly initialized, I am not able to proceed.

Comment: The cost function is minimized when $y_i^T x \to -\infty$, i.e. there is no minimum.

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in $\lim_{\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x\to-\infty} \frac{\sum_i\mathbf y_i^T}{\sqrt c}\cdot\frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|}
$

Comment: I can verify that $J$ is concave over its domain for $c > 1$, but that doesn't seem to help me a lot other than that if $\|\mathbf x\|$ is bounded after each step, the magnitude of the gradient is also bounded, and the (mis)-alignment might occur faster/earlier, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment with the negative direction of $\sum \mathbf y_i$ can be proven via the GD update rule:
$$\mathbf x^{t+1} = \mathbf x^t - \eta\nabla_\mathbf xJ$$

Taking the inner product with $\sum \mathbf y_i$ and using distributive property, we have
$$\left(\sum_i \mathbf y_i\right)^T\mathbf x^{t+1} = \left(\sum_i \mathbf y_i\right)^T\mathbf x^t - \left(\sum_i \mathbf y_i\right)^T\eta\nabla_\mathbf xJ$$
$$=\left(\sum_i \mathbf y_i\right)^T\mathbf x^t - \eta\frac{J^2}{c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)}
$$
Dividing by the norms of $\sum \mathbf y_i$ and $\mathbf x^{t+1}$, $\sqrt c$ and $\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|$respectively, we have
$$\frac{(\sum \mathbf y_i)^T\mathbf x^{t+1}}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|\sqrt c} = \frac{(\sum \mathbf y_i)^T\mathbf x^t}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|\sqrt c} - \eta\frac{J^2}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|c\sqrt c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)}$$

Now we multiply and divide on the right side by $\|\mathbf x^t\|$:
$$\frac{(\sum \mathbf y_i)^T\mathbf x^{t+1}}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|\sqrt c} = \frac{\|\mathbf x^t\|}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|}\frac{(\sum \mathbf y_i)^T\mathbf x^t}{\|\mathbf x^t\|\sqrt c} - 
\frac{\|\mathbf x^t\|}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|}\frac{\eta J^2}{\|\mathbf x^t\|c\sqrt c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)}$$
$$= \frac{\|\mathbf x^t\|}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|}\left[\frac{(\sum \mathbf y_i)^T\mathbf x^t}{\|\mathbf x^t\|\sqrt c} - 
\frac{\eta J^2}{\|\mathbf x^t\|c\sqrt c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)}\right]$$

Note that the term on the left describes the cosine of the angle $\theta^{t+1}$ between $\mathbf x^{t+1}$ and $\sum \mathbf y_i$. Similarly, the first term inside brackets on the right denotes $\cos \theta^t$
$$\cos \theta^{t+1} = \frac{\|\mathbf x^t\|}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|}\left[\cos\theta^t - 
\frac{\eta J^2}{\|\mathbf x^t\|c\sqrt c}\sum_i{\exp(\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x)}\right]$$
Because $\frac{\|\mathbf x^t\|}{\|\mathbf x^{t+1}\|} < 1$ since $\|\mathbf x\|$ grows, and the update term is always positive, we have
$$\cos \theta^{t+1}<\cos\theta^t$$
which implies that
$$\lim_{\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x\to-\infty} \frac{\sum_i\mathbf y_i^T}{\sqrt c}\cdot\frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\cos\theta^t=-1
$$

---

Note that it can be concluded from the above arguments that if $\|\mathbf x\|$ is small the angles decrease faster. If it is fixed to $k$, we have a projected GD (PGD) on the $k$-hypersphere. In that case, PGD will oscillate around the optimal alignment with the intensity of such oscillation determined by the choice of $\eta$ and $k$.